# Is it legal to define constants with the same name in different modules?

Tags: ruby

I have the constant LOGGER defined in two Ruby modules, assuming that since they were in separate name spaces, this would be ok

```
module Key
  ...
  LOGGER = 'logger'
  ...
end
```

and elsewhere

```
module ThePlatform
  module Monitoring
    ...
    module Key
      ...
      LOGGER          = 'logger'
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But this results in warning messages:

```
warning: already initialized constant ThePlatform::Monitoring::Key::LOGGER
```

Is this legal in Ruby?  Is there a best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL; DR

> warning: already initialized constant ThePlatform::Monitoring::Key::LOGGER

Your error comes from *redefining* a constant that belongs to a given namespace. There's nothing stopping you from having constants that share a name as long as they are in different namespaces.

### Example

Consider the following simplified example:

```
module Foo
  LOGGER = :log1

  module Bar
    LOGGER = :log2
  end
end

Foo.const_get :LOGGER
#=> :log1

Foo::Bar.const_get :LOGGER
#=> :log2
```

In this example, you can see that each of the namespaced constants hold different values. So, it's perfectly legal to do this, and won't raise warnings in otherwise well-formed code.

So, the problem lies elsewhere within your code. Most likely, you are redefining ThePlatform::Monitoring::Key::LOGGER twice, either by assigning to that specific constant more than once in your code—most likely (but not necessarily) somewhere within your Key module—or because at least one of your other modules is improperly nested.

Comment: You can test the theory presented by CodeGnome and sawa by running irb and loading these two files -- you should not see the error (assuming there is nothing more in them than you've shown).

Comment: "Improperly nested."  This.

Answer (score 1):

Defining constants with the same name in different namespaces is of course okay. That is the whole purpose of having a namespace.

However, in your case, the warning message says that what you think as belonging to two different namespaces are actually not. They are in the same namespace. Hence the warning. Notice that even in such case, it is not an error. Ruby can redefine a constant during run time. It is just discouraged.